# How to use Python to respond to cmd input areas

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python how do you respond to exe input fields

so lets say I have a exe that i ran and how could i reply to the bit where it would say

```
Password >
```

I have this code

```
# this asks for password
subprocess.call("server_post")

# then the password
subprocess.call("password")
```

Comment: no that doesn't work just tried it

Comment: Perhaps you could give more detail? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: It appears that he's asking how he can "answer" to STDIN on the subprocesses.